# How to use sfNumberValidator?

Tags: symfony1, yaml

I have a problem : I try to use the sfNumberValidator, but it doesn't work.

This is my validator.yml file :

```
methods:
 post: [lib_modele_controle, frequence_controle, intervenant_controle, delai_alert_controle, mode_operatoire_controle]


fillin:
  enabled: true      # Active la repopulation

names:


  delai_alert_controle:
    required: true
    required_msg: Veuillez renseigner le d&eacute;lai d'alert
    class: sfNumberValidator
    param:
     nan_error: saisir un nombre
```

In my form, when text is enter, or a number, the error is not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you work with symfony 1.0 as you use validation in yml.

Is you indentation consistent? I'm not sure if it's a problem or you just pasted it wrong but some lines are indented with two and some with one space.

Indentation has to be consistent.